# THREE.js - vertex's coordinates of BufferGeometry (ObjLoader)

Tags: three.js, vertices, buffer-geometry, objloader

I'm new to Three.js, and have an issue with getting coordinates of 2 verticies. I need their x,y,z coordinates to calculate and draw sizes.

I used ObjLoader and I know exactly ID's (indexes) of verticies - 11889 and 11877.

I tried to use some properties of BufferGeometry, but, obviously, wrong. So here is the simple code I'm staying with.

```
                var coord1 = [11889,0,0,0], coord2 = [11877,0,0,0];

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();      
            mtlLoader.load(
                'bath1.mtl',
                function( materials ) 
                {
                    materials.preload();
                    oLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    oLoader.load('bath1.obj', function ( bath ) 
                    {
                        bath.name="bath1";
                        bath.position.y -=1; bath.position.x -=0.25; bath.position.z -=1;
                        scene.add( bath ); 
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {},
                    function ( error ) {console.log( 'An error happened' );}
                    );

                }
            );
```

I read a few similar questions, but I could not adapt the answers for my problem. What should I do to get coordinates? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can use [`.fromArray()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3.fromArray) method of `THREE.Vector3()`, this way:

```js
var geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 5);
var bath = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());

var vert1 = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(bath.geometry.attributes.position.array, 1 * 3);
var vert2 = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(bath.geometry.attributes.position.array, 2 * 3);

console.log(vert1, vert2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Another approach is to use [`.getXXX()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferAttribute.getX) methods of `THREE.BufferAttribute()`:

```js
var geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 5);
var bath = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());

var position = bath.geometry.attributes.position;
var x = position.getX(1);
var y = position.getY(1);
var z = position.getZ(1);

console.log(x, y, z);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I've thried somethig like this. And I always have that "bath.geometry is undefined" error. May be I use somewhere wrong? Here are examples, what I did [link](http://rsidorkf.beget.tech/bath/bath.html) [link](http://rsidorkf.beget.tech/bath/bath1.html)

Comment: @flay_x If you do `console.log(bath)`, you can see, that it's not `THREE.Mesh()`, but, I bet, it will be `THREE.Group()` or `THREE.Object3D()`. Thus you have to work with the children of the `bath` object.